Inconsistent Java Builds Using NetBeans and Ant
I have a Java Ant project in Netbeans that automatically generated the build script. During development, I used NB to compile and build the code. This consistently generates a jar file that is 140 KB in size and functions as expected. However, when trying to build src code in a different directory using the exact same build files in the cmd line with
ant clean jar

I get a different jar file that is 288 KB and doesn't function properly.
In the correct jar file built using Netbeans, my JTree is populated with information. In the other one, the information is missing.
Missing Info
Correct Fucntionality
I have tried modifying the build. I have copied and pasted the entire contents of the NetBeans project folder into my new directory to ensure everything is the same, and I still get a different build.

Not really sure how those largely obliterated images are really meant to help, but most likely you have a different approach set in your IDE (Netbeans) than is set in the Ant build file. I would suggest you use Maven or Gradle as the build system, as only people using Netbeans use Ant (often unknowingly) any more. If you had to share your project as a generally buildable entity, you would likely have trouble. Unfortunately, your information is very general so this is a general comment that will help you in the long run. If I had to guess, I would say the issue is a resource management problem
